# How can I load more data on scrolling down in ion-select in ionic2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2, ionic2-select

[image]

I want call any method when scrolling down so that i can load more data at that time like ion-infinite-scroll.

Comment: Well, that's tricky. You could have each row call a function when they become visible and, by incrementing a counter, know where you're at on your list. When the counter is near the end, append the displayed model with some more data.

Comment: How I can call a method when row was visible? Is there any predefined method in ionic2

Comment: Are you able to do this? I also want the same.